# Passing multidimensional with dynamic form via ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm developing an invitation system to our platform. The end user will be able to add as many users as he want. For that, I prepared a dynamic form:

**HTML:**

```
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user0first_name" name="user[0]first_name" placeholder="First Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user0last_name" name="user[0]last_name" placeholder="Last Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user0email" name="user[0]email" placeholder="Email" />
                </div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#invitation").click(function(event){
    var data = {};

    for (var i = 0; i <= emailIndex; i++) {
       data["user[" + i + "]first_name"] = $("#user" + i + "first_name").val();
       data["user[" + i + "]last_name"] = $("#user" + i + "last_name").val();
       data["user[" + i + "]email"] = $("#user" + i + "email").val();
    }

    console.log(data);
```

**PHP**

```
    $name = $_POST['user'];

    foreach( $name as $v ) {
        print $v['first_name'];
    }
```

This just print me the "email" column:

**Email1valueEmail2value**

I need to catch the first name and last name too.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript:

```
$("#invitation").click(function(event){
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= emailIndex; i++) {
   var obj = new Object();
   obj.first_name = $("#user" + i + "first_name").val();
   obj.last_name = $("#user" + i + "last_name").val();
   obj.email = $("#user" + i + "email").val();
   data.push(obj);
}
console.log(data);
```

PHP

```
$name = $_POST['user'];
foreach( $name as $v ) {
    print $v['first_name'];
}
```